# How do I change the URI of rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uri

When I tried to run my Rails project on a local server, an error message (from the addressable gem) appears:

> Absolute URI missing hierarchical segment: 'http://:9200' (Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError)

How would I go about changing my Rails project's URI so that it can be valid?

**My setup:**

- Ruby 2.1.2
- Rails 4.1.1
- Addressable 2.4.0

Comment: You can do something like this 
rails s -b YOUR_URL_IP

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't seem to work. The local server is running in the correct location, but Addressable is still raising the same error message.

Comment: which version of addressable and ruby are you using ?

Comment: Why are you not providing the `localhost` part of the URL?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal When I run the server or when I look for in my browser, I am using the address `http://localhost:3000/`. `http://:9200` is just what is coming out of my error message. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem of an undefined environment variable (ElasticSearch_URL), which led to ElasticSearch giving out an invalid URL.

This problem was identified by the ":9200", which is the default port that ElasticSearch uses.